# Why are the details entered using PHP stored as $_POST['name'] when using XAMPP?

Tags: php, html

```
<table rows="5" cols="2" cellspacing="20%"  >
<form method="POST" action="<?php $_PHP_SELF ?>">//form for username password
<?php

$conn = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","web");
if(! $conn )
{
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysqli_error());
}
if(isset($_POST['uname'])){ $usname = $_POST['uname']; }//variable assigned
if(isset($_POST['pwd'])){ $pswd = $_POST['pwd']; }       // variable assigned

// variable @_post['pwd"] is saved in the db instead of that data

mysqli_query( $conn,"INSERT INTO `login`(`username`,    `password`) VALUES ('$usname','$pswd')");

echo "Entered data successfully\n";
mysqli_close($conn);// php close

?> 

<tr> //table row
 <td >Username</td>
 <td><input type="text" name="uname"  ></td>
</tr>
// table row is given
<tr>
  <td >Password</td>
//password label is specified
  <td><input type="password" name="pwd"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
   <td><input type="button" name="sign" value="sign in" onclick="validate()" > </td>
// table date


</form> //form close tag
</table>
```

Comment: I don't get your question. Can you explain what is wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Learn to escape quotation marks if not, separate them this way:

```
mysqli_query( $conn,"INSERT INTO `login`(`username`,    `password`) VALUES (".$usname.",".$pswd.")");
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not xampp doing this, it is Apache. The server that is handling your requests. Apache, just like other servers like Windows IIS, Nginx, etc.. need to follow all Method definitions specified here:

http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html

Also your code is as insecure as writing in mysql_* functions. If you are going to use MySQLI or PDO, do it correctly using parametrized queries. If not at least escape them:

```
if(isset($_POST['uname'])){ $usname = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['uname']); }//variable assigned
if(isset($_POST['pwd'])){ $pswd = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['pwd']); }       // variable assigned
```